# Check Mockito method call verify()

Tags: java, mockito

I have a test in jUnit4:

```
@Mock
MyWebClient myWebClientMock;

@Test
public void testOnOpen() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("OnOpen");
    Session session = null;
    MyWebClient instance = new MyWebClient();
    instance.connectToWebSocket();

    instance.OnOpen(instance.getSession());
    Mockito.verify(myWebClientMock).sendPing();
}
```

In last row of the code I check did I call method `sendPing()`.
I pretty sure this method is called inside of `OnOpen()` method:

```
@OnOpen
@Override
public void OnOpen(Session session) throws IOException {
    this.session = session;
    sendPing();
}
```

When I make debug I figured out it was really invoked. But why `Mockito.verify(myWebClientMock).sendPing()` doesn't pass ?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    @Test
    public void testOnOpen() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("OnOpen");

        MyWebClient instance = new MyWebClient();
        instance.connectToWebSocket();

        MyWebClient spy = Mockito.spy(instance);
        spy.OnOpen(instance.getSession());
        Mockito.verify(spy).sendPing();
    }
```

That works. Thanks for your tries.

Comment: Careful using spy in this way is doing a partial mock, and partial mocks are wrong design wise. You should instead have a separate collaborator that you will mock and inject in your webclient. Then you you will verify on that mocked collaborator if `sendPing` is called.

Comment: `spy.OnOpen(instance.getSession())` made me cry.  If you're going to use spies in this way, you need to understand that the spy is actually a separate object from whatever you made it from.  Having a test which interacts partially with the spy and partially with the original object is a recipe for disaster.  Do not write your tests this way.

Answer (score 3):

Because you didn't invoke `sendPing` on the mock, you invoked it on the object referenced by `instance`.

Are you testing `MyWebClient`? Or are you testing some other component that uses `MyWebClient` and therefore have to mock `MyWebClient`? In this case you seem to be testing a specific component, but mocking putting expectations on a mock. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand how make it properly. Can you correct my code ?

Comment: @alerya No, I won't correct your code because I don't know what you are trying to do. What you **are** doing is invoking a method on one object, but expecting it from another.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like MyWebClient is the class under test it doesn't make sense that you would also mock it. You should be mocking any classes that collaborate with MyWebClient.

If you are testing the OnOpen method then you should be asserting that the session has been set correctly, and then also sendPing has done whatever it is supposed to do. If sendPing calls some other class then you could mock that and verify the interactions with it.